# Is it possible to disable an OSGi component programmatically in CQ?

Tags: osgi, aem

Rather than manually making configuration changes to OSGi components in Felix, it's good practice to create `sling:OsgiConfig` nodes in the JCR to make sure that the settings are version controlled, applied the same across environments, etc.

Similarly, I want to disable an out-of-the-box component on each environment. Is there any way to achieve this via configuration? Rather than going to `system/console/components` and disabling it there?

Anything I've read about this has mentioned making changes internally within the bundle, but since it's one that I don't own, I'd need some external configuration to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `ScrService`, which is published by the SCR runtime bundle. API documentation is [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Fapache%2Ffelix%2Fscr%2FScrService.html).

Note that ScrService is not "standard", i.e. it doesn't come from the OSGi specification. However it is supported by Felix and Equinox and Knopflerfish, so it's pretty much a *de facto* standard. In fact this service is used by the Web Console when you go to `system/console/components`.

Comment: Is there a plan to include ScrService in future OSGi specs? It looks very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use attribute `policy=ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE` on `@Component`.

Then you could prepare a set of packages with configurations for each environment as part of the build. This is also a good practice for having different OSGI configurations for each environment.

So for some of enironments you could just simply not provide a configuration for a particular component. Such component would not run - it would have unsatisfied status.

I believe I've seen this approach in AEM itself.

You can also create a filter to remove current configurations but it still would require to disable the Component at least once. And this solution will work only if this component has mentioned policy.

The other way around is to prepare a Service that would be responsible for disabling other components - it could be configurable. But it doesn't sound like a good solution to me.

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for your answer. The trouble I'm having is that the component that I want to disable is one part of a compiled JAR provided by Adobe, so I'm unable to make modifications to the annotations.

Comment: Could you specify which component is it and why do you want to disable it?

Comment: I've extended my answer a bit but is still would be useful to know what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to disable the component so as to provide my own implementation of the Service that it exposes. As I understand it, if two versions of the same service are available, it's the OSGi runtime that will resolve which implementation is used, so I could get either.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, each OSGI service can have a [SERVICE_RANKING](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#SERVICE%5FRANKING) property, which is used to prioritize service and the service with the highest ranking is returned. The other option is to use filter in OSGI `@Reference(target = "(feedbackType=data)")`. Please extend your question so I could edit my answer.